# Nuxt 3 useFetch data possibly null errors when using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Typescript on my Vue page and trying to fetch user data from API.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
    const { data: user } = await useFetch('/api/user/info', {
        headers: useRequestHeaders(['cookie'])
    });

    if (!user.value)
        throw createError('Problems when fetching current user!');

    const myComputed = computed(() => !user.value.login); // <-- Error!
</script>
```

However I get tons of errors!
When I try to use `user.value` in `script` I get `user.value possibly null` errors and inside `template` I get `__VLS_ctx.user possibly null` errors.

Errors disappear when I remove `lang="ts"` attribute from `script` but I don't want to do this. How to fix this problem?

My API:

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async event => {
    const userId = await getTokenUserId(getCookie(event, 'token'));

    if (!userId)
        return setResponseStatus(event, 403);

    const db = await getDb();
    const dbUser = await db.manager.findOneBy(User, { id: userId });

    if (!dbUser)
        return setResponseStatus(event, 404);

    return {
        login:      dbUser.login,
        isEditor:   dbUser.isEditor,
        topics:     await getUserTopicsListInfo(userId),
    };
});
```

Comment: Remember you're using a strongly typed language with TypeScript.  You must supply type information or these are the errors you will run into.  We don't know what actual type your `user` object is, but at the very least you can provide `any` type:  `const { data: user }: any = await useFetch(...)`, although this is just a way of bypassing TypeScripts type safety features and you _should_ provide an actual type if you can.

Comment: The return type of `data` is computed automatically by Nuxt and it is correct (`login`, `email` and etc.). But why TS does not respect that I already have `if` to check for incorrect data?

Comment: you may use `user.value?.login` instead of `user.value.login`

Comment: @DengSihan Using `?.` like fifteen times does not look like a good idea to me. And even if I do, it does not solve the initial problem - why it is marked as error if I preformed null check.

Comment: Your API does not appear to adhere to RESTful principles, which typically involve responding with appropriate status codes such as 404 or 401 when a resource like `/api/user/info` yields a null user (assuming this endpoint is meant for retrieving the profile of the currently authenticated user). In scenarios where you're working with RESTful APIs, or any APIs where errors are consistently managed in responses, it would be more efficient to use a wrapped useFetch method. This approach allows for uniform error handling, eliminating the need to manage errors separately on each page.

Comment: @DengSihan what do you mean by "wrapped" method. Are you talking about `onRequest`, `onResponse` and other things? And yes, my API can return 403 and 404 codes with `setResponseStatus(event, 403);`...

Comment: The code is type-unsafe, you don't use result types. In a simplified manner it can be something like `const { data: user }: { data: Ref<MyResult> } =`. Since you don't refetch it and it's guaranteed to be non-null after a type guard, this type assertion is acceptable

Comment: @EstusFlask yeah but it also means that I have manually write result type. But Nuxt automatically detects return type from my API route and displays type hints inside vue page. So... why write down the type manually?

Comment: Because it's also inferred to be null which you're trying to avoid. I'm not aware of this behaviour, can you clarify what the type looks like and how this works? It couldn't detect the exact response type for random urls. Generally you'd need to specify response type though a generic, useFetch<MyResult>(...). You can keep as much inferred types as possible through temp vars, e.g. `const { data } = ... ; const user: Ref<NonNullable<UnwrapRef<typeof data>>> = data` or custom useFetch wrapper

Comment: @EstusFlask The type is just an object with simple user data: id, login, email... If `auth` token is wrong I return `403` with `return setResponseStatus(403)`. I will update my question. My VS Code automatically show type hints from API return (like `login`, `isEditor` and so on).

Comment: @EstusFlask "Because it's also inferred to be null" yes, but I have an `if` condition for this case. Why it shows errors even after this `if`? My only guess is that because `user` is a reactive, its value might change and kind of bypass this `if`... But I am not familiar with this reactive stuff...

Comment: Then inferred type is probably specific to IDE and you may need to type it to build properly. "if" typeguard would likely be ok as is if you accessed user.value.login immediately after, but you access it inside a computed, it could change by then, at least from compiler's point of view

Comment: @EstusFlask Oh, yeah I see... I guess I just need to write my own type (as I did earlier today and it worked) and maybe also wrap `useFetch` in order not to send cookies by hand everty time. I will do it tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using a wrapped `useFetch` method to handle the errors uniformly instead of managing errors separately on each page could be a better practice.

This answer will not directly answer your current question but will solve all problems that got unexpected API responses.

---

define a `useCustomFetch` as a wrapped `useFetch`, which got exactly the same params and return as `useFetch`

```js
export const useCustomFetch = (
    URL,
    options = {}
) => {
    return useFetch(
            url,
            {
                ...options
            }
        )
            .then(({ data, pending, error, refresh }) => {
         
                if (error.value) {
                    
                    // you may handle the errors here uniformly

                    // throw error;
                }
                return {
                    data,
                    pending,
                    error,
                    refresh
                };
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                throw error;
            });
    });
};
```

Now, you add the code before sending and after the response. (just like  the interceptors in axios)

```
if (error.value) {
                    
    // you may handle the errors here uniformly

    const {
       statusCode,
       statusMessage,
       data
    } = error.value;

    // use the nuxt error page
    // https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/show-error
    showError(error.value);    
    
    // or you can redirect to the specific pages when got `4XX` responses (`/404`/ `/401`)
    navgiateTo(`/${statusCode}`);

    // also, destroy the current token if got 401
    if (statusCode === 401) {
        authStore.logout(); // here is an example
    }

    // or send a notification to the user
    if (process.client) {
       notify({
          type: 'error',
          title: `${statusCode} ${statusMessage}`,
          text: data?.message ?? 'Something went wrong'
       });
    }
}
```

---

What's more, you don't need to add the `headers: useRequestHeaders(['cookie'])` each time you use `useFetch`, you can add it once and use it everywhere.

```js
    ...
    
    let headers = options?.headers ?? {};

    headers = {
        ...useRequestHeaders(['cookie']),
        ...headers
    };

    options.headers = headers;
 
    useFetch(
       url,
       {
            ...options
       }
    )

    ...
```

---

After this, you can use `useCustomFetch` to replace `useFetch`

Comment: Wrapping a promise with new Promise is an antipattern. Also the type is wrong because useFetch returns a promise-like that can omit await but useCustomFetch doesn't

Comment: @EstusFlask I have modified the code to conform to the pattern. Thanks a lot for your correction!

Comment: OP's issue is related Typescript; this seems overkill and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Null check the value, it might solve the issue?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    const { data: user } = await useFetch('/api/user/info', {
        headers: useRequestHeaders(['cookie'])
    });

    if (!(user && user.value))
        throw createError('Problems when fetching current user!');

    const myComputed = computed(() => !(user && user.value && user.value.login)); // <-- Error!

</script>
```

You can also use the non-null assertion operator !

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    const { data: user } = await useFetch('/api/user/info', {
        headers: useRequestHeaders(['cookie'])
    });

    if (!user!.value)
        throw createError('Problems when fetching current user!');

    const myComputed = computed(() => !user!.value!.login); // <-- Error!

</script>
```

Comment: I dont want to check for null every time I use `user` because I use it like 15 times. Adding `user === null || user.value === null` to `if` condition does not solve the problem. I don't understand why  VS Code can't see I have checked for `null` already.

Comment: The declaration `myComputed` is separated from the rest in Composition API, it doesn't have to maintain the execution order. You can easilly put it at the first row and it won't be a problem. But because of that, VS Code is sadly unable to tell "you have checked for null already".

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning error codes `4**` from your API function, there will be no `data` and therefore `user.value` can be `null` in some cases.

This is how the return type taken from [Nuxt docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch): `data: Ref<DataT | null>`

Also check the behavior in [this StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-nuzyh2?file=app.vue) - my API function is randomly returning data or an error 50:50 and writes the objects in the console. Refresh it couple of times to see that always either `data` or `error` is `Ref<null>`.

That's why TypeScript is correctly pointing out for you that just checking `!user.value.login` is not enough. If `user.value` is null, calling `.login` would fail.

You need optional chaining: `!user.value?.login` will avoid this case easily with no extra boilerplate code.

But you will probably start facing another issue, because untyped `useFetch` data will be inferred to `{}` (empty object) and TypeScript will start complaining that `.login` does not exist there.

So you would also need to define your own type: `await useFetch<YourType>(...)` to clear all the errors.