# How to catch the network errors with global error handler in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I am trying to log into an API and want if there are **any**** sort of errors, they should be captured by the global error handler defined in plugins.

My login code in Vue+Nuxt 3 looks like this  - so here I am throwing a custom error so that it reaches the global handler

```
try {
    const response = await useAsyncData(
      $fetch(`${baseUrl}/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: username.value,
          password: password.value,
        }),
      }),
    );
    data = response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    // console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    throw createError({
      statusCode: 500,
      message: "An error occurred while trying to log in.sss",
      cause: error,
    });
  }
};
```

but what I see is the error in console is -

```
An error occurred while trying to log in.sss
```

my plugin look like this -

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.config.errorHandler = (error, instance, info) => {
    // handle error, e.g. report to a service
    console.log("in nuxtApp.vueApp error handler", error, instance, info);
  };
});
```

I expect it be used in any sort of error that arises with application not only vue+nuxt3 specific.

What am I doing wrong here? Any guidance would be appriciated.

Comment: Dose [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77601634/10519069) answer your question that handling the network errors uniformly?

Comment: I don't wanna use showError to display the error.vue page and then ask the user to back to the previous page. This can be used in rare cases, but mostly I wanna display errors in the form of alerts on the same page, so I just wanted to capture error and handle them own my own.

Comment: Yeap, you can use any handler for the network errors instead of `showError`

Comment: @skr are you looking for a full solution that you only need to copy/paste once into your app?  The code show in the other question is exactly how to create a global error response with nuxt.  The exact kind of response is up to you, you only need to copy the code that matters.

Comment: @yoduh, Well, I am not sure where I mentioned I need a copy/paste answer, but never mind. Thank you for such a helpful answer. I already looked at that code, and I didn't like it. There are better approaches, what I am trying here is to find out why my custom error does not reach the global error handler plugin I created.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the official example mentioned here on the Nuxt website in advance error handling section: https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/advanced/error-handling

So, instead of using `createError` , now I am using simple `throw Error()` or  `throw new Error()` in catch bock as shown below and this works as expected.

```
try {
    const response = await useAsyncData(
      $fetch(`${baseUrl}/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: username.value,
          password: password.value,
        }),
      }).catch((error) => {}),
    );
    data = response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw Error("manually triggered error");
  }
```